Java SQL JDBC Error al conectar a un servidor externo
Estoy diseñando una aplicación y se conecta a un servidor SQL. Para ello uso MySql Workbench en un ordenador destinado a ser el servidor. Cuando estoy trabajando en mi portátil y pruebo las cosas de la aplicación conectándome a un servidor que está en mi portátil no hay ningún problema pero cuando lo paso a otro ordenador para que se conecte al servidor (alojado en la misma red) hay veces que no se conecta y otras que si. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

hay veces que no se conecta y otras que si. ¿Podrías explicar cómo te estás conectado? Por ejemplo,  podría ocurrir que en la cadena de conexión estás poniendo la IP del equipo donde se aloja la base de datos. Si se conecta unas veces y otras no, puede que la IP de ese equipo no sea fija en la red. En todo caso, haz un seguimiento de los mensajes de error, los cuales te dirán sin duda por qué no se está conectado.

Como están en el mismo grupo de trabajo de windows no especifico la IP sino el nombre del equipo, en este caso SERVIDOR

Me conecto usando una libreria de Java
`
tring usuario="PUESTO2";
String contrasenia="At@9414C";
String bd="baseschema";
String ip="SERVIDOR";
String puerto="3306";

String cadena = "jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":"+puerto+"/"+bd+"?useSSL=false&connectTimeout=5000";

`
¿Puede que sean los puertos y el firewall?

Puede ser cualquier cosa. ¿No estás implementando manejo de excepciones en la conexión? Revisa el mensaje de error, el cual te dirá el motivo específico por el cual no está conectando.

Ya he encontrado el fallo, era el firewall de Windows que cerraba los puertos
